# Draytek Vigor Firewall

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall, draytek

I have a Draytek router (Vigor 2865) which i have had for a while, and whilst its a great router, a have a few queries regarding the firewall & WAN security:

Outline of my WAN Connection - Standard VDSL with a single dynamic IPv4, and i think multiple IPv6's, (Each device has a different IPv6, although my knowledge of IPv6 *is* limited). Router performs NAT. I use a dynamic DNS system. Simple.

Obviously, i want the firewall deny all incoming connections type setup. All ports should be 'stealthed', inbound. Absolutely no response. The only exception to this should be where the VPN server (On the router) is listening. I initially thought that the router would do this by default: The 'Default Rule' in the firewall config is set to pass, (Which i think is needed otherwise outbound packets would get blocked?) like this:

[image: Draytek Default Rule Config]

And the firewall 'General Setup' looks like this:

[image: Draytek Firewall General Setup]

I think i saw somewhere that the 'Block routing connections initiated from WAN' was only for non-NAT setups, hence it is enabled for IPv6 but not IPv4, but i don't know? Should i tick the box for v4 too?

And finally, i don't usually have any rules in the firewall filter sets to explicitly block inbound connections from the WAN. Do i need to add these?

Interestingly, i did try, as a test, adding a rule like this:

```
Direction: WAN -> LAN/DMZ/RT/VPN
Src IP: Any
Dest IP: Any
Service Type: Any
Action: Block Immediate
```

however looking at the logs when this rule in enabled, they are getting full of block's like this:

```
[FILTER][Block][WAN->LAN/RT/VPN, 436:15:10 ][@S:R=2:2, x.x.x.x:80->192.168.20.32:40064][TCP][HLen=20, TLen=52, Flag=AF, Seq=2525108200, Ack=2848724396, Win=256]
```

with x.x.x.x (The source IP) being some WAN IP, often a Google, Microsoft, Amazon etc datacenter, and the destination IP being one of my local machines, but interestingly, the source port is often something like 80, 443, etc, whereas the destination port on the local machine is a very high port, like in this case 40064. This, in addition to the fact that i really don't think all these blocks are just the random internet scans one can expect (The source IP's often correspond to services i may be using, such as Outlook or something), makes me wonder if this rule is blocking responses to connections being established by my machine (But i am no expert)?

However, nothing seems to stop working with this rule enabled...

Sorry for the long post, just basically trying to make sure my firewall is setup in the most secure way possible in this situation. Usually i am fine with that kind of thing, but some things here have me a little bit confused...

P.S - I have also noticed certain weirdness with the router exposing the HTTPS web interface, even though management from WAN should be disabled, just because i enable the 'SSL VPN Service'. Anyone else experienced strange things like that?